# window.ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"}) automatically picks the connected account when making a transaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, accounts

I have multiple accounts on my Metamask wallet(Most of them are connected to the site). But my selected account is not connected to the Dapp. So, when I try to send a transaction it uses one of the connected account without requesting to connect to the currently selected account which is not connected.

```
const getWeb3 = async () => {
  let web3Instance;
  let accounts;

  if (window.ethereum) {
    web3Instance = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    try {
      accounts= await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("User denied account access");
      throw new Error("User denied account access");
    }
  } else if (window.web3) {
    web3Instance = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.error("No web3 instance found, please install MetaMask");
    throw new Error("No web3 instance found, please install MetaMask");
  }

  return { web3Instance, accounts };
};

export default getWeb3;
```

*In the image, you can see I have selected the account(not connected)  '**0x17796B3914AD5A68b8133539b6b0B518276D0187**' but the retrieved account(connected) from code is '**0x316f8D0B8bEf2cA0396202272A18Db46fE2C7232***

[image: In the image, you can see I have selected the account(not connected) '0x17796B3914AD5A68b8133539b6b0B518276D0187' but the retrieved account(connected) from code is '0x316f8D0B8bEf2cA0396202272A18Db46fE2C7232']

Comment: what are you using to deploy your dApp?

Comment: I am using truffle and ganache as my local environment.